# Break while loop with timer?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, break

I was wondering is it possible to break a while loop with a timer?
looked on the internet but could not find a solution for it.

```
while (true) {
  alert('hi');
} if (timer < 0) {
 timer?
 document.write('Time is up!');
 break;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: best way to implement this is javascript `setTimeout`

Comment: Your example is too broad, as of that giving an answer is not easy. You should change your example code, so that  it will show why you need the `while(true)` loop. Do you only need it to pause it execution until the time is up or do you want to do anything within the loop until the time is up?

Comment: Since JavaScript is single-threaded, as long as you're stuck inside the loop nothing else can be evaluated, including something in a setTimeout. The timed callback will be queued and evaluated only when the currently running code has completed. There is probably a solution (not involving a loop) to your actual problem, but *not to your silly example*.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response.
I was wondering if I could break a loop by using a timer.

I am constructing a qwiz a list of questions and I want to add a timer so that if the player is in the game and takes to long a timer will show that he losses and can try again

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setTimeout` for this.

```js
var timer = 3;
setTimeout(excuteMethod, 1000);

function excuteMethod() {
  alert(timer + ' call');
  timer--;
  if (timer >= 0) setTimeout(excuteMethod, 1000);
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/9s9z7adt/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, but it works,

```js
(function() {
  var delay = 30;
  var date = new Date();
  var timer = date.setTime(date.getTime() + delay);
  var count = 0;

  function validate() {
    var now = new Date();
    if (+now > timer)
      return false;
    else
      return true;
  }

  while (true) {
    count++;
    console.log(count);
    if (!validate()) {
      console.log("Time expired");
      break;
    }

    // Fail safe.
    if (count > 50000) {
      console.log("Count breached")
      break;
    }
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change control value in timer function and break the loop.

```
var control = true;
while(control)
{
    ...
}

setTimeout(function(){
    control = false;
}, delay); //delay is miliseconds
```

Or based on counter

```
var control = true,
    counter = 10;

while(control){
    ...
}

// you can handle as count down
// count down counter every 1000 miliseconds
// after 10(counter start value) seconds
// change control value to false to break while loop
// and clear interval
var counterInterval = setInterval(function(){
    counter--;
    if(counter == 0)
    {
        control = false;
        clearInterval(counterInterval);
    }
},1000);
```